# How to send nicely formatted mails in R

Tags: r

I use below mentioned code to send mails, can I change the format of table which will pasted on mail body, I want to send nicely formatted/compacted table in mail body.

first6 is my data.frame

```
Date=sys.Date()-1
date2 <- paste("My subject of mail", Date, sep = " - ")
setwd("/xyz")
newdir <- paste("output", Sys.time(), sep = "_")
dir.create(newdir)#, showWarnings = FALSE)
setwd(newdir)

######
mydoc = bsdoc( title = 'my document')
options( "ReporteRs-fontsize" = 8 )
mydoc = addParagraph(mydoc, value = "Hi All, \n\nPlease check attached summary.")
mydoc = addParagraph(mydoc, value = "Summary:")
MyFTable = FlexTable( data = first6, add.rownames = FALSE, header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color = "#FAEBD7" )
                      , header.par.props = parProperties(text.align = "center" ))
MyFTable = setColumnsColors( MyFTable, j=1, colors = '#F0F8FF' )
MyFTable[ , ] = parProperties( text.align = 'center')
MyFTable = setColumnsColors( MyFTable, j=ncol(first6), colors = '#F0F8FF' )
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, MyFTable )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "op2.html" )

send.mail(from = "abc@xyz.com",
          to = c("abc@xyz.com"),
          subject = date2,
          body = "op2.html",
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "abc@xyz.com", passwd = "xyz@123", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

[image: table looks in mail]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, but I think you need to use the right tool for the right job.

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

You can find other options at the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm